# How to access root Class when there's a duplicate name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, root

Check this simple sample:

```
public class Someone{       // [the:A]
}

public class Another{
    public class Someone{   // [the:B]
    }

    public class DoSomething{
        **how can I access Someone in root, which is [the:A]**?
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing simple in this example.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "global::" keyword, or use a using; statement at the top.

```
global::YourNamespace.Someone
```

or, in your using statements:

```
using SomeoneRoot = YourNamespace.Someone;
```

and in the event that there's an ambiguation in your namespaces, the global:: keyword can be used there too:

```
using SomeoneRoot = global::YourNamespace.Someone;
```